# gravity attribute on android xml not working

Tags: android, xml, gravity, android-relativelayout

I just started android programming . I have been writing xml in `RelativeLayout` and find that `gravity` attribute isn't working . Every element in layout overlaps each other. I am aware that there may be better ways to do positioning  but I am curious to know , what is it ,that I am not doing correct ? Please help me out

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <TextView 
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/message"
                 android:gravity="start"
            />

           <Button  
              android:id="@+id/btnclose"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:background="#780956"
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:onClick="close"
              android:text="close"
              android:gravity="bottom"
        />
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/btnclick"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="close"
        android:text="click"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not just use gravity

there are two types of them
 gravity ,layout-gravity

one affects all the elements and other won't

try both of them..

Answer (score 0):

As you are using RelativeLayout, right way to position views are using below attributes:

1. android:centerInParent
2. android:layout_toLeftOf
3. android:layout_toRightOf
4. android:layoutBelow

Read more about [Positing Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using RelativeLayout, set properties this way:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnclose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#780956"
        android:onClick="close"
        android:text="close"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnclick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="close"
        android:text="click"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```